# Call a python function on button click in discord_components (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, interaction

I am making a bot in `discord.py`, and I want to call a function inside the code whenever someone presses a button. I looked at the documentation of `discord_components`(lib for buttons and select menus), but it's either I'm stupid or the documentation is bad. I also googled it but didn't find anything.

So is it possible to run a function on the interaction event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    your_func()
```

You can just go with the flow. Be careful not to forget to send a callback.
Here is the link to the event examples on the discord components github: [examples](https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components/blob/master/examples/event.py).